# How do I specify which field should be displayed with MVC Scaffolding

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I am creating an MVC4 application using EF Code First database.  I am working with some foreign key declarations.  I wish to use define the field to display in the dropdown in the scaffolding in the model declarations.  For instance:

My simplified model declaration is as follows:

```
public class Contact
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Middle { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return (Last + ", " + First + " " + Middle).Trim(); }
    }
}

public class Role
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public string RoleDescription { get; set; }
}

public class RoleAssignment
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Contact")]
    public int Contact_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Role")]
    public int Role_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

I generate the standard scaffolding and the edit .cshtml looks like this:

```
 <fieldset>
    <legend>RoleAssignment</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contact_ID, "Contact")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Contact_ID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contact_ID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Role_ID, "Role")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Role_ID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Role_ID)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

However, the dropdown uses the "Prefix" field for the drop down and display.  I want it to use the "FullName" field.  How do I designate this in the Contact model declaration?  (I know how to do this my modifying the .cshtml code, but I want it to work with pure generated code.)

Answer (score 1):

OK. Figured it all out.  To specify a custom naming field for your table for drop-downs, use the "DisplayColumn" on the model class, and then use the "NotMapped" attribute to prevent the custom display field from being mapped to the database, and give it a setter that does nothing:

```
[DisplayColumn("FullName")]
public class Contact
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return (Last + ", " + First + " " + Middle).Trim(); }
    }
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Middle { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial answer to my question:

Adding the "DisplayColumn" attribute to the model class allows you to change the display field for the scaffolding as follows:

```
[DisplayColumn("First")]
public class Contact
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return (Last + ", " + First + " " + Middle).Trim(); }
    }
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    public string First { get; set; }
}
```

However, it does not work with the read only field "FullName".  Still trying to figure that one out...

Comment: It works, you just have to add `[NotMapped]` because yeah, it's not a column in your db